# Web deploy azure web role with multiple instances

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a windows azure web role that has 2 instances.  I would like to web deploy to these instances from VS as to avoid doing a full deployment that takes ~ 10 - 15 minutes.

I know this used to be possible with the [now deprecated] Azure Accelerator for Web Roles.  Is this possible now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Deploy still works, but only for single instances and only for testing purposes (ie. you can't use it for a production site where you expect the changes to persist across VM reimages or node movements).

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud/archive/2011/04/19/enabling-web-deploy-for-windows-azure-web-roles-with-visual-studio.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683672.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

To enable Web Deploy, you must install the Windows Azure Tools and the Windows Azure SDK from the Microsoft Web Installer 3.0 page of the Microsoft website.

But, be aware, you cannot have multiple instances of any web role in your deployment environment. However, multiple web roles each with only **one instance are supported**.